# How to route to Angular components based on query strings?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, query-string, angular5, angular4-router

I'm using the Angular 4/5 currently and let’s say I have 2 components **Component 1** and **Component 2**. Now, I know that with the help of routing, I can access each of them using the routes array of type ROUTES in which I'll specify the `path` and `component` properties for each of these components. 
The problem is that I want the URL for both of the components like this:

Component 1:

> http://localhost:4200/?property1=value1&property2=value2

Component 2:

> http://localhost:4200/?property1=value3&property2=value4

Although I know that I can include the query strings with the help of `queryParams` parameter but I'm able to do this by including the path property also which is not desired in my case. 
So, can anyone help how can I route to these components based only on the query strings and not including any other useless material?

Comment: Perhaps you can have a parent component with both Component 1 & 2 as children in it (I'm assuming you only have two child components) and conditionally show either one based on the the value of the params you get.

Comment: @ThomasJiang, Ok, but how to do that? Sorry, but I'm a beginner in Angular. I have included both of these components A and B inside the app folder and I'm confused if you are asking to show these components  by the use of Angular or by some other logic?